# What does motor writing mean in neurology?

Tags: neuroscience

In Zoltan Torey's The Conscious Mind, the author discusses the emerge of language:

> Adding weight to the thesis of the stage-wise evolution of language, Bickerton (1995) noted that
>
> the linguistic history of the hominid line appears … as a two-stage process: first a stage in which there was a lexicon without syntax, then a stage in which infinitely productive mechanisms emerged to create syntax as we know it. If this conclusion is correct, it is a waste of time to look for antecedents of syntax in ancestral species, as syntax could not have come into existence until there was a sizeable vocabulary whose units could be organized into complex structures.
> … There seems no feasible alternative to concluding that syntax has a specific neural substrate, laid down at some stage prior to the last fifty millennia, most probably at the time when anatomically modern humans emerged as a separate species.
>
> Bickerton’s description is spot on, though it does not say what the “infinitely productive mechanisms” and the “specific neural substrate” for generating syntax actually were. To find these, we turn to **the motor writing of the speech areas** in the human infant’s neuroplastic brain, the break- through that gave it the leverage to handle its lexicon and generate syntax when, through feature-detection, it acquired qualifiers and function words.

From the beginning of the book, the author has referred to this breakthrough as "the speech areas acquiring a motor-arm, which is the language. Now he says "motor writing", but I can't get the exact meaning of "writing" here!

Comment: There's no specific meaning to this term. Probably a typo for motor *wiring*.